# is there api for After rate_save_vote?

Tags: rating

I want do something after the eventAfterRate in php,
and I have use the rate rules http://drupal.org/project/voting_rules  ,the result turn out not after,and the same as implement the hook_rate_widget_insert.
so is there api for  After rate_save_vote?

Answer (score 0):

Rate relies on the [Voting API module](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi), which exposes [`hook_votingapi_storage_add_vote()`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_votingapi_storage_add_vote/7):

> Save a vote in the database.

```
function hook_votingapi_storage_add_vote(&$vote) {
  _mongodb_votingapi_prepare_vote($criteria);
  mongodb_collection('votingapi_vote')->insert($vote);
}
```

I don't know of a Rate-specific hook but you might get somewhere using that one (all depends what you need to do I guess).